# No error for varchar(2500) in Oracle?

Tags: oracle10g

I read some where that varchar stores 2000 bytes whereas varchar2 stores 4000 bytes. Then, can you tell me why can I still create the below table structure in ORacle 10g or Oracle 11g?

`CREATE TABLE sample
(
col1 VARCHAR(2500)
)`

Oracle should have given the error for above query but it is not, can any one explain whats going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you read that the limit on a VARCHAR is 2000 bytes?  The [Database Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits001.htm#i287903) lists the data type limits.  Both VARCHAR and VARCHAR2 have the same 4000 byte limit.

Comment: I think I might have read it for very older version of Oracle. If they're same, then what's the difference?

Comment: Also, if I use varchar(10) & if I'm using only 4 characters, then the extra space is still wasted in Oracle 10g??

Comment: @Mike - I don't believe the limit has ever been different.  At a minimum, any version of Oracle released in the last 15 years has treated VARCHAR and VARCHAR2 identically.  One is actually defined as a subtype of the other.  Neither use more storage space than is required for the data you actually store in the column.  The difference is that VARCHAR is an ANSI standard type and Oracle holds out the possibility that some time in the future, they will change the semantics of the VARCHAR type to match the ANSI standard in which the empty string is not NULL.

Comment: I read about 2000 bytes at below url: `http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_is_the_difference_between_varchar_varchar2_and_char_data_types` Look at the comment by Kalyani there...She mentioned that varchar takes space & is of 2000 bytes. Which one is correct???

Comment: @Mike - That URL does not appear to be valid.  If we have to choose between the official Oracle database documentation and some random comment on a web site, particularly when the database documentation matches reality, I'd believe the official documentation.  Potentially,  the comment you refer to is comparing the CHAR and VARCHAR2 data types since CHAR is fixed width and limited to 2000 bytes.

Comment: I was referring to this url: [link](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_is_the_difference_between_varchar_varchar2_and_c‌​har_data_types)

Comment: @Mike - Kalyani's comment is mostly incorrect.  It also doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.  Immediately after claiming that VARCHAR is fixed width, the comment says that "Oracle resolved this... by casting VARCHAR to VARCHAR2".  Even assuming the intention was to say the two types were synonymous rather than that one was cast to the other, the comment is self-contradictory.  The comment about the maximum lengths is incorrect.

Comment: @Mike let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1137/discussion-between-justin-cave-and-mike)